# How can I keep alive the previous page use a method to push?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How can I keep alive the previous page ?

I have a list page, and I have a paginator in this page.
and I use the `this.$router.push` to push to the detail page:

```
  go_details(h, params){
    let query = {
      id: params.row.id
    }
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'physicalserverDetails',
      query: query
    });
  },
```

and in the `physicalserverDetails` I use the `this.$router.go(-1);` go back.

but, there is a trouble, if in the list there is at `page 5`, I go back from `physicalserverDetails`, the list page will refresh `page 1`, not `page 5`.

I know in general I can use `keep-alive` tag to achieve the target,

```
<keep-alive include="index">
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

but however there must be using `this.$router.push(xxx)` to go with it, because the detail page is a common page, has many entries.

How to do with it?

Comment: How is your pagination set up though? Your router does not magically know about your paginatio. If you refresh the page and you would not pick up the pagination state by using a query parameter or something, it would be obvious you would start at page 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store the page number in the URL as a query parameter. That way the page number will be "remembered" in the router history since it exists in the URL.

You can bind the query parameter to a prop in your component (see [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)). You can [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) it or use the [`beforeRouteUpdate`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) hook to load the next page when its value changes.

If you have previous/next buttons, all you need to do is make them a [`<router-link>`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link) that has the `page` query parameter set to the corresponding page.

This doesn't keep the previous page in memory (like `<keep-alive>` would), but you know what page number should be displayed in response to route changes because you can just check the `page` query parameter. It also fixes the problem that Stephan-v pointed out in the comments, in that refreshing the page will preserve the page number.